# How to fix runtime osx.10.11-x64 for UAP,Version=v10.0

Tags: .net, macos, .net-core

I have a sample application (the fork is : https://github.com/cpoDesign/Windows-appsample-trafficapp)

When I run:
following commands:

```
bash-3.2$ dotnet restore
bash-3.2$ dotnet run
```

I have received following error

> Can not find runtime target for framework 'UAP,Version=v10.0'
>   compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'osx.10.11-x64'. Possible
>   causes:
>   1. The project has not been restored or restore failed - run `dotnet restore`
>   2. The project does not list one of 'osx.10.11-x64' in the 'runtimes' section.
>   3. You may be trying to publish a library, which is not supported. Use `dotnet pack` to distribute libraries.

**After this I have updated my project to provide osx desciption**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.0.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "uap10.0": {}
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-arm": {},
    "win10-arm-aot": {},
    "win10-x86": {},
    "win10-x86-aot": {},
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win10-x64-aot": {},
    "osx.10.11-x64":{}
  }
}
```

After providing the runtime
I have run again my dot net commands above

**And this time I have got**

```
**bash-3.2$ dotnet restore**
log  : Restoring packages for /Users/user/Desktop/code/trafficApp/Windows-appsample-trafficapp/TrafficApp/project.json...
log  : Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: /Users/user/Desktop/code/trafficApp/Windows-appsample-trafficapp/TrafficAp
p/project.lock.json
log  : /Users/user/Desktop/code/trafficApp/Windows-appsample-trafficapp/TrafficApp/project.json
log  : Restore completed in 647ms.

**bash-3.2$ dotnet run**
Can not find runtime target for framework 'UAP,Version=v10.0' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'osx.10.11-x64'. Possible causes:
1. The project has not been restored or restore failed - run `dotnet restore`
2. The project does not list one of 'osx.10.11-x64' in the 'runtimes' section.
3. You may be trying to publish a library, which is not supported. Use `dotnet pack` to distribute libraries.
```

**What do I need to update?**

Comment: I don't understand, why are you trying to run a UAP/UWP (which is Windows-specific) app on OSX? Why would you expect that to work? It's called Universal *Windows* Platform for a reason.

Comment: @svick you are correct, & explains everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Universal App Platform / Universal Windows Platform is Windows-specific. As far as I know, there is no way to run a UAP/UWP app on OSX.